# How to add another field in a join sails js

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sails.js, nosql

Hey all just getting started with Sails js and mongoDB and im a bit confused.

I have two models with a many-to-many relationship:

User.js

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    username: 'STRING',
    password: 'STRING',
    doors:{
        collection: 'door',
        via: 'users',
    }
  }
};
```

and Door.js

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    name: 'STRING',
    users:{
        collection: 'user',
        via: 'doors'
    }
  }
};
```

This works fine, I can create a user and a door and associate one with the other. However I'd like to have another field in the join, an expiry date (Say the user can only have access to a particular door until a particular date).

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a many to many *through* association. However they are not officially supported as of yet.

You can manually do this however.

Now, in this example it may sometimes be a a little more difficult to get all the doors for a user and vice versa, because you have to preform a second look up. However you can do the following with this setup:

```
UserDoors
    .find()
    .where({expires:{'<':new Date()}})
    .populate('doors')
    .populate('users')
    .exec(/*....*/)
```

Your models

```
User.js

module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    username: 'STRING',
    password: 'STRING',
    doors:{
        collection: 'userDoors',
        via: 'users',
    }
  }
};


userDoors.js
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    doors:{
        model: 'door'
    },
    users:{
        model: 'user'
    },
    expires: 'datetime'   
  }
};



and Door.js

module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    name: 'STRING',
    users:{
        collection: 'userDoors',
        via: 'doors'
    }
  }
};
```

Do a google search for `sails.js many to many through`  to also help you find what your looking for.

Comment: Something interesting has happened, I implemented your suggestion and it worked fine with the sails-disk adapter, however when switching to the sails-mongo adapter it appears that sail doesn't see the relationship any more.

Is there any limitation in mongodb? I've noticed it uses a particular format for the id column but have taken that into account.

Comment: hmmmm. That is strange. I would confirm all your code looks good an check out the data your querying to make sure it got inserted correctly. I have a relationship setup just like this in mongo and it works.